Volver atras una kb sin git
Mi inconveniente es que elimine por error un objeto y un sdt los cuales requiero traer devuelta o programar todo de cero.
Alguna idea de como podria hacerlo ?  estoy en genexus 18

Tente utilizar essa extension: https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?recoverobject,en
